# Destructuring and clone object / One line?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm using `react.js`, and I want to obtain from the state an array, but I required to clone it and save it into a `const`. I can do it with two lines of code; exists a way to do it in a single line of code?

Example:

```
const { data } = this.state
const newData = [...data]
```

FYI, I'm using eslint, and with `"parser": "babel-eslint"` config and VSC show me a warning if I'm trying to do this:

```
const data = [...this.state.data]
```

Warning message: `Must use destructuring state assignments - lint react / destructuring-assignment`

I don't want to remove/customize the rules of eslint... but I don't want to extend the code more than necessary.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can create an Array slice of `this.state.data` through destructuring all in one line:

```
const { data: [...newData] } = this.state
```

Caveat, this is not a *deep* clone if you're expecting that. It's just a new Array referencing the original Array items.

Note that I think your eslint rules are insane to *require* using destructuring. It's not *always* the best solution.

Comment: Well, yes... I'm also thinking that is "too-much" requires destructuring... I will check the way to not put this rule as a warning. Thanks for the heads-up!